# Click an icon, run an UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to have an UPDATE query run when I click an icon on a web page. I just need to have the image have the proper call function in onclick to run the mysql from the corresponding php file.

The page already loads and displays all values in a list associated with $show_id, so that variable is already being pulled from the web page in to the php code. I just need to be able to pull that variable in to the query below and have it run when I click on the icon associated with it.

This is code I have in the php file:

```
function retired()
{
if(strlen(($_POST['retired'])) > 0){

$sql = "UPDATE ttb_books SET status_id = '2' WHERE show_id='$show_id'";
$db = new database();
$db->myquery($sql, 1);
header('Location:books.php?show_id=$show_id');
die();
    }
}
```

This is the current image/form html:

```
          <form method="post" action="books.php?show_id={show_id}">
          <input type="image" src="../images/icon-Red_Light.png" width="20" name="retired" alt="Set status to Out of Print" title="Set status to Out of Print" onclick="return confirm('Set ALL status to Out of Print?')">
          <input name="shid1" type="hidden" id="shid1" value="{show_id}" />
          </form>
```

So the onclick would call the function with that mysql string and update all items in the list accordingly.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: also inline JS is a bad practice. For one-liners it's ok, but for project maintainability (and readability) it just makes things 100x harder

Comment: I don't see any javascript nor a form. The value `$show_id` is that a GET or POST variable? Please add sufficient code to replicate the problem

Comment: This is in the admin side, so it isnt visible/ accessible to anyone but me, so I'm not worried about injections. As for $show_id, that is part of the full php code that is attached to the html file: books.html & books.php. That variable works fine, so all I need to do is pull it in to the query when I click on the image icon, and have the page reload. No frills, just a simple function call and the query runs.

Comment: If you're "not worried about injections" then you're doing your job wrong. Please read about SQL Injection and how bad it could be. Nonetheless, you may want to use AJAX to connect the frontend click event with the backend.

Comment: Again, this is the admin panel. If someone is already accessing the admin panel, they can rip it all apart anyway and injections wouldnt be very useful at that point.

Comment: That's some horrible approach and I hope you reconsider your position on that matter. Security and user-input validating is always needed.

Comment: You should use something like PDO and [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) to execute the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do this on that icon :

At first, you need to put your $show_id, call it from your DB and put it to the link below

```
<a href="actionsite.php?update=show_id">
    <img src="../images/icon-Red_Light.png" width="20" name="retired" alt="Set status to Out of Print" title="Set status to Out of Print"/>
</a>
```

And this on the `actionsite.php` :

```
$show_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['update']);
$query = $db->query("UPDATE ttb_books SET status = 37 WHERE show_id = '$show_id'");
echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>";
```

Hope this can help you...

Comment: You're not sanitizing the user-given data. That may lead to SQL injection.

Comment: People can add they own sanitize, I just explaining how it works.

Comment: Some people doesn't know about SQLi and they may just copy-paste your code. **That's dangerous.**

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! I just added the sanitize function. May it help them :)

Comment: How about using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)? :)

Comment: So the image is now

<a href="books.php?retired={show_id}"><img src="../images/icon-Red_Light.png" width="20" name="retired" alt="Set status to Out of Print" title="Set status to Out of Print"></a>

and the function is:

 function UpdateRetired()
 {
  $show_id= $_GET['retired'];
  $query = $db->query("UPDATE ttb_books SET status_id = '2' WHERE show_id = '$show_id'");
  echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>";
  
 }

It doesnt seem to do anything, except reload the page

Comment: @RudiPratama the paste isnt very clean, but am I missing something that is keeping your code from working? And I did add your sqli update, too

Comment: I've just seen the above additional code - please add all code to the question and not to a comment

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the main question block. I decided to go the form route, so the image is an input object instead of just an icon. I compared it to a different script I have elsewhere on the site. The only issue now is that with the php lines the page loads with an error. When I comment them out, it loads fine. The form tags load fine on the html side, so only the code on the php file has an issue that isnt working on this page.

Comment: You need a javascript help to submit a form without refreshing the whole page. About an Error on your page, what line is causing the error? Can you put that in here...

Comment: I just updated the code in my initial post with the current iteration. All that happens right now is, when I click the form image, it reloads the page, but it isn't activating the function and running the query. For some reason it isn't calling it and I can't figure out why, since I have code that's almost identical elsewhere doing the same thing and running fine.